# Bootstrap Navigation Drawer not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am trying to use bootstrap nav drawer(available here: http://clineamb.github.io/bootstrap-drawer )
I tried to work on example.html provided by uploader but was unable to make it work.I know ,I may have committed the mistake somewhere but don't know what went wrong(as am new to this).Please help me out.

The drawer content is hidden but when i try to click on < a> tag (menu),it does nothing.

```js
<script>
($('.drawer').drawer());      
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://clineamb.github.io/bootstrap-drawer/dist/css/drawer.js"></script>
<script src="https://clineamb.github.io/bootstrap-drawer/dist/js/drawer.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
    <link href="plugins/Drawer/css/bootstrap-drawer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="plugins/Drawer/css/bootstrap-drawer.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/Drawer/js/drawer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     
    <link href="plugins/Drawer/example/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="plugins/Drawer/example/highlight.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body class="has-drawer"> <!-- add this class to your body for proper sizing -->
    <div id="drawerExample" class="drawer dw-xs-10 dw-sm-6 dw-md-4 fold" aria-labelledby="drawerExample">
        <div class="drawer-controls">
            <a  data-toggle="drawer" aria-foldedopen="false" aria-controls="drawerExample" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Menu</a>
        </div>
        <div class="drawer-contents">
            <div class="drawer-heading">
                <h2 class="drawer-title">Menu</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="drawer-body">
                <p>
                    This is a properly padded container for content in the
                    drawer that isn't a navigation.
                </p>
                <a href="#">A Regular Link</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="drawer-nav">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="drawer-footer">
                <small>&copy; Caroline Amaba</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- content as per usual -->
    </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is fine, you have simply just forgotten to target the `id` in the `.drawer-controls` button, i.e `href="#drawerExample"` :

```
<a data-toggle="drawer" href="#drawerExample" aria-foldedopen="false" aria-controls="drawerExample" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Menu</a>
```

your code working here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/14e95rpr/**